# fadeOut function makes entire page content disappear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Basically, I am trying to give a notification to user whether they were successful in adding their file and said notification disappears after 3 seconds. Problem is my entire page faded out instead of just the notification. It worked with my other pages just wondering why it worked differently on this one. Session variables are set from what I checked.

Here's the code for the script:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        $('.success').fadeOut(3000);
        $('.failure').fadeOut(3000);
    });
    </script>
```

Here's the code for the page:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){
    echo "<div class = 'success'>".$_SESSION['success']."</div>";
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['fail'])){
    echo "<div class = 'failure'>".$_SESSION['fail']."/div";
    unset($_SESSION['fail']);
}
?>
<div>//some form code here</div>
```

Comment: your rendered html ????

Comment: is `."/div";` just a typo when entering the question here on SO, because if it isn't, looks as thought you have invalid HTML i.e. should be `."</div>";` with the angle brackets. Which would mean the failure tag was not closed properly and consequentially could mean every element that comes after will be its child, so when hiding .failure would also hide a lot more than you want

Comment: didn't notice that typo there...quite a few of my pages have the same code so I must have seen it wrong after looking back and forth between those pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that because you are missing your "<" and ">" on the div close:

```
echo "<div class = 'failure'>".$_SESSION['fail']."/div";
```

Since the div doesn't close the rest of the page might be interpreted as part of it.

See if this works:

```
echo "<div class = 'failure'>".$_SESSION['fail']."</div>";
```

Comment: wow I didn't notice that typo over there for an hour now...it's working now thanks

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect:

```
echo "<div class = 'failure'>".$_SESSION['fail']."/div";
```

It doesn't contain the ending bracket for the closing of the div. In this way the vrowser doesn't know that the failure div has been closed, so it will think that the rest of the content is inside it. To fix the problem, the line should be:

```
echo "<div class = 'failure'>".$_SESSION['fail']."</div>";
```

Comment: I must have missed that looking back and forth between pages that had a similar code...thanks